# Finding max value of float in a string - regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm confronted with such a challenge right now. I've read some web classes and Dive Into Python on regex and nothing I found on my issue, thus I'm not sure if this is even possible to achieve.

Given this dict-alike string:

```
"Mon.":[11.76,7.13],"Tue.":[11.76,7.19],"Wed.":[11.91,6.94]
```

I'd like to compare values in brackets at corresponding positions and take only the greatest one. So comparing `11.76`, `11.76`, `11.91` should result in `11.91`.

My alternative is to get all the values and compare them afterwards but I'm wondering whether regex could cope?

Comment: do you need a regex solution?

Comment: I mean anything that would work would be great.

Comment: I mean that already looks like a dict, you could just convert it to one.

Comment: Are you sure you will always see a dict-like string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

text = '''"Mon.":[11.76,7.13],"Tue.":[11.76,7.19],"Wed.":[11.91,6.94]'''
values = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', text)
values = map(lambda x: x.split(','), values)
values = zip(*values)
print max(map(float, values[0]))
print max(map(float, values[1]))
```

Output:

```
11.91
7.19
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import ast
>>> text = '''"Mon.":[11.76,7.13],"Tue.":[11.76,7.19],"Wed.":[11.91,6.94]'''
>>> rows = ast.literal_eval('{' + text + '}').values()
>>> [max(col) for col in zip(*rows)]
[11.91, 7.19]
```

Comment: Give me what you drink jamylak xd This is excellent stuff again. Have you read books on python or learnt the code mostly reading sites like stackoverflow?

Comment: This will not compare the values in corresponding positions -- it compares all the values. From the question, I understood that the OP wants to have an answer like `[11.91, 7.19]`

Comment: @nutship Mostly online things eg. (SO, Python docs). Do you need to also get the max one from each block?

Comment: @Dhara I'm not sure if OP actually needs that. If so I would lose order... Also don't you mean `[11.76, 11.76, 11.91]`?

Comment: Yes, Dhara is right on this. I'd need to get `7.19` as well, for the final output of `[11.91, 7.19]`

Comment: And sorry guys I messed up a bit. Actually I need a regex solution because I'm using it so scrape a website and wanted to compare the values on the fly.

Comment: @nutship hold on does my updated code do what you want? Or you can't use it since it's not regex?

Comment: Actually I can only use regex. But your answer was of a great help anyway. I think I will retrieve all the values from the website I'm scraping with regex and then use your code to do the rest.